# I cant get external image on my NextJS app hosted on Git Pages, instead of images I get alt text. How can I fix it?

Tags: image, next.js, github-actions, github-pages

My next.config.file
[next.config.file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqFP3.png)
In browser you can see like this [Chrome screenhot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmbVj.png)
I url for external image is https://picsum.photos/200/300
Why I cant see image?

I try to add config my next.config.file but it doesn`t help me

Comment: All work well on, localhost and vercel. But on GitHub Actions I have this trouble

Comment: Hi and welcome. Can you inline your code as text, not as image or as image. It is then much easier to read/help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the domain in the `next.config` file like so:

```
const withImages = require('next-images');
module.exports = withImages({
  images: {
    domains: ['domain.com', 'anotherdomain.com', 'yetanotherdomain.com'],
    disableStaticImages: true,
  },
});
```